# What is this cogset body?

Tags: hub, freewheel, sprocket, freehub

I have some backlash (free movement) in my body of cogset, so I try to dissemble my cogset to discover this weird body:

[image]
[image]

I'm trying to find a new one but I don't know how to call it. Any idea how it can be called ?

(Sorry, I'm french, I try to find translation for word, but I hope the picture help)

Comment: All freehubs and freewheels have some amount  of freedom of movement.  At worst its the gap between two teeth inside.  Worst known one is up to 11 degrees of motion before the pawls catch, which is a campagnolo freewheel.  Could be that you are chasing a problem that is normal behaviour?

Comment: It's good to have photos, but please crop them and use the auto-level function in your editor before uploading them. Ideally resize them too. That will make the upload faster and the images easier to understand.

Comment: @Criggie, I'm not sure I understand you. The freedom of movement is inside the freehub body (the picture, between the axis inside and the axis the outer part of the body). 11 degrees here you be massive !!! do you mean between the the teeth inside (freedom of movement in rotation ?)

Comment: @Mσᶎ, sorry for that...I'll do it next time !

Comment: I finally open the freehub, clean everything inside and remove one of the washer (there were 3). We assumed the freedom of movement was coming for the roller-bearing, and removing one washer allow to tight the freehub and the backlash decrease a lot. The brand and reference of this object remain unknown to me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a freehub body.

Look on the hub for the model of hub you have, and then you can use that to find the appropriate freehub body model by looking at the documentation of the hub.

Comment: yes that where we started looking at, but we cannot find anything written...

Comment: If its original to the bike, you can look up the model of the bike and likely find what kind of hubs the bike was shipped with. Alternatively, give it to a bike shop along with a wheel and they should be able to figure it out.